# (Python) How to enable Grease Pencil Tools Add-On using python

Tags: python, add-on

I'm writing an addon that uses some functionalities of "Grease Pencil Tools" add-on that comes by default with Blender, but is disabled by default.

I would like to automatically activate it in the code of my own Add-On.

Here is an exaple of code that I am trying to use:

```
import bpy
import addon_utils

addon_utils.enable("greasepencil_tools")
```

Unfortunatelly I'm getting this errors:
[image]

I'm not quite sure what is going on. I guessed it tries to run register() function of the add-on that was already run before and throws an error?

Please help!

Thank you so much for any hints!

Mac

Comment: Hello ! You can either check if the addon is already registered or use a `try: ... except ValueError: pass` Note though that on a User Experience perspective, activating third party content (even if it's shipped with Blender) without the user's knowledge or validation is arguably bad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually completely agree with your argument regarding starting another addon without user doing it by themself. I might just end up hiding the features related to the addon unless it is enabled and let users know that if they want these features they will show up when they activate the addon themselves.